# Jquery rating stars not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code is html of a simple star rating system.

```
<div class="review-stars clearfix" id="featured">
   <fieldset data-component-bound="true" class="star-rating-widget">
      <legend class="offscreen">Rating</legend>
      <ul class="stars-0">
         <li>
            <input id="rating-1" name="rating" value="1" type="radio">
            <label for="rating-1">1 (Eek! Methinks not.)</label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input id="rating-2" name="rating" value="2" type="radio">
            <label for="rating-2">2 (Meh. I've experienced better.)</label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input id="rating-3" name="rating" value="3" type="radio">
            <label for="rating-3">3 (A-OK.)</label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input id="rating-4" name="rating" value="4" type="radio">
            <label for="rating-4">4 (Yay! I'm a fan.)</label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input id="rating-5" name="rating" value="5" type="radio">
            <label for="rating-5">5 (Woohoo! As good as it gets!)</label>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <p class="description">Select your rating.</p>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#rating-1').hover(              
               function () {
                  $('#featured ul').removeClass();
                  $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-1');
               }, 

               function () {
                  $('#featured ul').removeClass();
     });
     $('#rating-2').hover(              
               function () {
                  $('#featured ul').removeClass();
                  $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-2');
               }, 

               function () {
                  $('#featured ul').removeClass();
     });
     $('#rating-3').hover(              
               function () {
                  $('#featured ul').removeClass();
                  $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-3');
               }, 

               function () {
                  $('#featured ul').removeClass();
     });
     $('#rating-4').hover(              
               function () {
                  $('#featured ul').removeClass();
                  $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-4');
               }, 

               function () {
                  $('#featured ul').removeClass();
     });
     $('#rating-5').hover(              
               function () {
                  $('#featured ul').removeClass();
                  $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-5');
               }, 

               function () {
                  $('#featured ul').removeClass();
     });

    $('#rating-1').click(function() {
        $('#featured ul').removeClass();
        $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-1');
    });
    $('#rating-2').click(function() {
        $('#featured ul').removeClass();
        $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-2');
    });
    $('#rating-3').click(function() {
        $('#featured ul').removeClass();
        $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-3');
    });
    $('#rating-4').click(function() {
        $('#featured ul').removeClass();
        $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-4');
    });
    $('#rating-5').click(function() {
        $('#featured ul').removeClass();
        $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-5');
    });
});
```

Here class of `ul` make changes to the background position of the star image. That means `ul class = "stars-0"` will show no star selected, `ul class = "stars-1"` will show 1 star selected..... (That is not the issue). When people will hover on any radio button then the corresponding class will be added to `ul` and on hover out again it will be removed, On click same will happen.Upto this it is working fine. But Once a radio is checked then the mouseout event should not work to keep `ul`'s class active. How can i do that. One more thing, the jquery i have written seems having a lots of code. Is there any way to reduce lines and optimize. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce lines and optimize you can use general class `rating` instead of `id`s and data-attribute `index` contain index of every `li` like code bellow.

I know this is not the perfect way to do what you want but it work fine, using data attribute `checked` to know if there's any checkbox checked or not yet, and `checked-value` to store the value of checked one so we can use it when the user hover out to preserve the checked class.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.rating').hover(              
    function () {
        var index = $(this).data('index');

        $('#featured ul').removeClass();
        $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-'+index);
    }, 
    function () {
        $('#featured ul').removeClass();
        
        if( $('#featured ul').data("checked") )
             $('#featured ul').addClass($('#featured ul').data("checked-value"));
    });

$('.rating').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).data('index');

    $('#featured ul').removeClass();
    $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-'+index);

    $('#featured ul').data("checked", true);    
    $('#featured ul').data("checked-value", 'stars-'+index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="review-stars clearfix" id="featured">
   <fieldset data-component-bound="true" class="star-rating-widget">
      <legend class="offscreen">Rating</legend>
      <ul class="stars-0">
         <li>
            <input id="rating-1" data-index="1" class='rating' name="rating" value="1" type="radio">
            <label for="rating-1">1 (Eek! Methinks not.)</label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input id="rating-2" data-index="2" class='rating' name="rating" value="2" type="radio">
            <label for="rating-2">2 (Meh. I've experienced better.)</label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input id="rating-3" data-index="3" class='rating' name="rating" value="3" type="radio">
            <label for="rating-3">3 (A-OK.)</label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input id="rating-4" data-index="4" class='rating' name="rating" value="4" type="radio">
            <label for="rating-4">4 (Yay! I'm a fan.)</label>
         </li>
         <li>
            <input id="rating-5" data-index="5" class='rating' name="rating" value="5" type="radio">
            <label for="rating-5">5 (Woohoo! As good as it gets!)</label>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <p class="description">Select your rating.</p>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, thats cool. but what about adding classes to `ul` on radio checked and do not remove that class untill new radio is checked?

Comment: Are you realy need to use hover and hover out here ? because just click can do the job.

Comment: Ya, click can do but on hover the rating value like poor, good, great etc will show on the right for making more user friendly.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a conditional that checks if a value is selected on the radio group already, like this:

```
 $('#rating-1').hover(              
     function () {
         if (!$("input:radio[name ='rating']:checked").val()){
              $('#featured ul').removeClass();
              $('#featured ul').addClass('stars-1');
         }
      },
```

As for the code duplication, one first step could be to create one or more helper functions in which you define the logic that is duplicated. But perhaps you should think of a way to make your logic more generic. You should be able to achieve the same functionality with just one hover listener and one click listener.